# Error when exporting R data frame using openxlsx ("Error in zipr")

Tags: r, export-to-excel, openxlsx

Usually I'm using the openxlsx package and the write.xlsx function when exporting R data frames into .xlsx-files. Since yesterday - probably after I was using the package XLConnect - something got messed up and the write.xlsx function doesn't work anymore. This is the error I get:

**Error in zipr(zipfile = tmpFile, include_directories = FALSE, files = list.files(path = tmpDir,  : 
  unused argument (include_directories = FALSE)**

Unfortunately, I don't understand what this error means. Thanks for any helpful advice.

**Edit:** The function works when I use an older openxlsx version (4.1.0).

Comment: I have the same problem. Had to install 4.1.0. again

Comment: Alternatively to reverting `openxlsx` to an _older_ version, you could update `zip` package to a _newer_ version. I got the same error when I was on zip version before 2.0.3, when the include_directories parameter was added. Try `packageVersion("zip")` to see which version you are on. The current version is 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.

I think the problem is with dependencies of openxlsx. There is a "zipR" package that might be picked up when you install openxlsx, while the actual dependency is zip package:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zip/index.html
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zipR/zipR.pdf

I installed "zip" along with openxlsx and I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: Hi, I still receive this error even I add library(zip) after library(openxlsx), could you please guide me how did you do? thanks!

Comment: For me updating the zip package worked. Before I had 2.0.0, which doesn't know the `include_directories` argument, since it was first introduced in 2.0.3. Try `packageVersion("zip")`, mine now is at 2.1.1, and with that it works fine.
[1] ‘2.1.1’

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand the error message here. My computer does not allow me to save files to "c:/". So, if remove "c:/" part, it works fine, to save the file to the current working directory.

```
library(openxlsx)
df <- data.frame('x' = c(1,2,3),
                 'y' = c(3,2,1))
openxlsx::write.xlsx(df, "test.xlsx")
```

You would also try another package: `writexl`

```
writexl::write_xlsx(df, "text5.xlsx")`
```

This works on my machine.

Comment: Thanks. It's just an example. The error message appears independently from the working directory.

Comment: I will try to reproduce what you have done on my side.

Comment: Yes, I have problems with installing and loading XLconnect, but your code still works on my computer. Alternative, you could try  another package: writexl::write_xlsx(df, "text.xlsx").

Comment: Yes, writexl works pretty well. However, I'm using other functions of the openxlsx package, such as importing excel data into R including formatting, manipulating data and protecting particular cells, before exporting them again. For this reason I have to use the saveWorkbook function in openxlsx - unfortunately, the same error message ("error in zipr") appears when I use this function.

Comment: This obviously is not a problem of your code. Since it works fine on my computer, it is difficult to fix issues other than those in your code on my side. If you post a separate question, you may get some answers from others.